# Apache Pig: group by and sum data

Tags: apache-pig

I have some data like:

```
type1, 2
type2, 1
type1, 3
type2, 4
type1, 5
type2, 3
type1, 1
type3, 5
type3, 5
```

I want to group them by type, the expected result should be:

```
type1, 11
type2, 8
type3, 10
```

Here is my PIG script:

```
data = LOAD 'my_data.txt' USING
   PigStorage(',') as (type:chararray, num:double);

a = GROUP data BY type;
result = foreach a generate data.type, SUM(data.num);

Dump result;
```

But I get this:

```
({(type1),(type1),(type1),(type1)},11.0)
({(type2),(type2),(type2)},8.0)
({(type3),(type3)},10.0)
```

How can I get rid of the multiple types in each record and only have one? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Finally found that there is a keyword in PIG called `group` which can help achieve this. The modified code is:

```
data = LOAD 'my_data.txt' USING
PigStorage(',') as (type:chararray, num:double);

a = GROUP data BY type;
result = foreach a generate group, SUM(data.num);

Dump result;
```

Hope it helps.